# trying to upgrade packages

Tags: upgrade, package-management, updates

Trying to upgrade my packages but I don't want to upgrade to 16.10.  I ran `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade my packages but got this message in terminal

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcjs0e : Conflicts: libcjs0 but 3.0.1-3build2 is to be installed
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat : Conflicts: packagekit
                              Conflicts: packagekit:i386
```

Should I purge/remove these packages and reinstall them?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just reinstall it.....and let us know

Answer (score 16):

I did this:

```
sudo apt-get purge python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
reboot

# after reboot
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The package `python3-apt-daemon.pkcompat` had no dependencies remaining. The upgrade then proceeded normally.

Comment: My upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 failed due to this problem. The above solution worked with apt replacing apt-get. Also, there was no need to do do-release-upgrade as apt upgrade did the necessary.

Comment: I ran all these commands as well as the second answer from Favian.  No show.  Eventually, I ran each of the packages listed from ... `apt list --upgradable` one-by-one.  I planned to update what I could/might and identify the _fly-in-the-oinmment_.  Turns out everything succeeded and what ever the mismatch _was_ was no longer. No idea what was in conflict -- Hope that work-around helps others.

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem in every situation :)
run:

```
sudo apt-get -f autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

then try again :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

My upgrade from 14.04 via 16.04 to 18.04 failed for the same reason.  Michael's solution worked when I used apt instead of apt-get.

```
sudo apt purge python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

"apt upgrade" failed partway through, but most of it completed when I ran a subsequent "apt purge" command.